# migrate command not found error even if migrate is installed

Tags: development-environment, migrate, npm-install

I have executed command - 
`npm install migrate` 
and it has executed successfully. But when I try to execute the command `migrate` in terminal it gives me error as `migrate command not found`
[Please find image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUlS6.png)

Has anyone got the same error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try installing it globally

`npm install migrate -g`

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions to this problem.

The first is to attempt to install the package globally.

**npm install -g migrate**

If above  solution not worked, it could be due to the current user's undefined ExecutionPolicy.

As an administrator, run the following PowerShell command:

**Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned**